# Call custom action using RABL gem? Rails 4 and RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

I have a custom action called `search` in my rails app that has two corresponding pages:

- `search.html.haml`
- `search.json.rabl`

The form that corresponds to the `search` method looks like this:

```
= form_tag(listings_search_path) do
      .input-group.search-input-group
        %span#search-icon-addon.input-group-addon
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
        = text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "        Search for spaces.", "aria-describedby" => "search-icon-addon"
      #search-btns.col-md-12
        = button_tag :Search, :class => "btn btn-default search-btns", :value => "Search"
        = link_to 'listings/findnearme', :class => "btn btn-default search-btns" do
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-map-marker
          Find Near Me
```

And the route:

```
post 'listings/search'
```

When I submit the form for html response, it works perfectly fine and calls the `search` method as intended:

```
# search method
def search
  @listings = Listing.search(params[:search].downcase)

  respond_with(@listings)
end
```

In the top of my controller (outside of any actions), I have:

```
respond_to :xml, :json, :html
```

But when I append `.json` to the url, it calls the `show` action instead.

How would I get JSON response from the `search` method?

---

**TL;DR**:

Calling "localhost:3000/listings/search" goes to the `search.html.haml` and calls the correct action `search`.

Calling "localhost:3000/listings/search.json" does **not** go to `search.json.rabl` and calls the `show` action instead.

Rails, Y U no call custom action?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you either need to add a (:.format) as an optional parameter to your route, or set the request type header.  You can try this in jQuery to invoke the JSON action:

```
$.ajax({url: '/listings/search', dataType: 'JSON', method: 'GET'})
```

Basically, the request type is not being picked up from .json and you either need to make the proper request type or set it via the route.